# std::promise error on cross compiling

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to cross compile a library in which uses C++11 and std::promise and other new templates defined in the  header. I get the following error:

```
error: aggregate 'std::promise<void> t' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

I have googled a lot and no one talk about using std::promise in embedded environment (which needs cross compiling). The test code is as follows:

```
#include <future>

int main ()
{
  std::promise<void> t;
  return 0;
}
```

The compile command is:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -std=c++11 -c  test.c
```

I tested on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit OS, with arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ version 4.8.
If I use g++ 4.8, the compilation passes.
What should be changed to pass the compilation ? Many thanks.

Comment: did you check the c++11 library state of your cross-compile toolchain? I had problems some time ago because c++11 library features were missing or not implemented

Comment: @MatthiasBonora thanks. There is a similar issue and an explanation in debian mailing list: [issue thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2013/12/msg00007.html). the command `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -std=c++11 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -c  test.c` succeeds

Comment: @golwatt `-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon` solves it for me too. If you succeeded too then you can make this an answer accept it.